# Angular. Using @viewchild to pass templateRef with service

Tags: angular

I am wondering if I can pass templateRef between sibling with service.

Simple example:

Child1

```js
export class Child1 implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('button', {static: true})
    private buttonTpl: TemplateRef<any>;
    
constructor(private service: ParentService) {}
    
 //some click method here 
  
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.button = this.buttonTpl;
}
```

```html
<ng-template #button>
  <button some click method >Click</button>
</ng-template>
```

Child2

```js
export class Child2 implements OnInit {

button;

constructor(private service: ParentService){}

ngOnInit {
  this.button = this.service.button;
}
```

```html
Child2 template:

I would like to show button here (as in toolbar) but have the functionality below.
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet='button'></ng-container>

Child1 content is routed here 
<ng-content select='.router-outlet'>
```

this is my service that is created at Parent level and should be accessible to children

```js
export class ParentService {
  button: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

When I had my ng-template #button and viewChild in parent component this service worked fine and I was able to render the button to Child2. But now when trying to pass between siblings this is not working. Is it even possible to use this method or shoud I try with something else?

edit: Parent html example

```html
<div>
  <child2>
    <router-outlet class='router-outlet'>
    //this contains child1
    </router-outlet>
  </child2>
</div>
```

Comment: Saying your code is "not working" isn't a particularly helpful description of the problem. We need to know what you expected to happen, what actually happened, and what error were thrown along the way.

Comment: Can you post your parent template html?

Comment: @TheHeadRush with not working I meant that the button is not visible. I expected It to be visible like It was before when I had the ng-template and viewchild in Parent component. I get no error messages.

Comment: @M11kkaL Thanks for the additional information. It looks like you are fetching the `templateRef` in `ngOnInit`. This hook is called before the component DOM is instantiated, so the reference is null. You probably need to move the assignment into `ngAfterViewInit` (and implement the appropriate interface).